# C# and Objective C Classes

Tags: c#, objective-c

I am just learning Objective C and was wondering what the correct way to create and use a class is.

In C# I can do something like:

```
Void MyMethod()
{
  MyClass clsOBJ1 = new MyClass();
  clsOBJ1.Name = “Fred”;
}
```

Or even

```
MyClass clsOBJ2;
Void MyMethod()
{
 clsOBJ2 = new MyClass();
}

Void MyMethod2()
{
 clsOBJ2.Name = “Bob”;
}
```

How would you achieve something similar in OBJ C?

I have tried this in OBJ C:

```
MyClass clsOBJ3 = [[[MyClass alloc]init]autorelease];
```

But I get the error message ‘MyClass Not Declared’

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I need to see more of your code to be sure but my guess would be that you havent imported the header for `MyClass`

At the top of your file look for:

```
#import "MyClass.h"
```

Or something similar

Comment: This is as I thought however when I put the import line in, I get an error saying the file can not be found. Yet it is there in the project!

Comment: The import is a file URL so the above import would only be valid if the file is in the same directory

Comment: Still unsure why it didnt work, I deleted and recreated my project and it worked. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

You would typically have the following:

MyClass.h

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
@private
   // your ivars here
}

// your property declarations and methods here
@end
```

MyClass.m

```
#import "MyClass.h"

@implementation MyClass

// synthesize your properties here

- (id) init {
    if((self = [super init]) != null) {
        // some init stuff here
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc {
    // your class specific dealloc stuff
    [super dealloc];
}
```

And in some other file you could then use *MyClass* as so:

SomeOtherFile.m

```
#import "MyClass.h"

- (MyClass *) createAMyClass {

    MyClass * mClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];

    return [mClass autorelease];
}
```

Comment: You would need the #import "MyClass.h" in SomeOtherFile.m